# Object's position moves when selecting multiple in fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

If select one object, there is no problem.

However, if you select two or more objects by dragging, the position of is moved as shown on the screen below.

[image]

[image]

Why is the value of "top" and "left" changing when you make multiple selections?

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle or working snippet showing the issue?

Comment: What's the solution to this problem?

Comment: I ran into this but only while dragging objects (or even a single object), clicking or shift clicking to select multiple does not create an issue like this.

Answer (score 2):

After trying n-number of solution I figured out the solution to this problem. It was something related to the **zoomed canvas**. Now it works fine!

Comment: Can you provide more information about the solution?